# Errors from passing a structure as a reference, using nested structure

Tags: c++, function, struct

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


struct Class
{
    std::string name;
    int units;
    char grade;
};
struct Student
{
    std::string name;
    int id;
    int num;
    double gpa;
    Class classes[20];
};

int get_info(Student students[100],const int);
double get_gpa(Class local_classes[20],const int);

int main()
{
    const int MAX_STUDENTS = 100;
    int num_of_students;
    Student students[MAX_STUDENTS];
    num_of_students = get_info(students,MAX_STUDENTS);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_students; i++)
    {
        int amount_classes = students[i].num;
        std::cout << "\n*******x2 = " << students[i].name;
        std::cout << "\n*******Units: " << students[i].classes[0].units;
        students[i].gpa = get_gpa(students[i].classes,amount_classes);
        std::cout << "\nGPA of " << students[i].name << " is: " << students[i].gpa;
    }

    return 0;
}

int get_info(Student students[100],const int MAX)
{   
    int counter = 0, local_id;
    while (counter < MAX && students[counter].id != -99)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter the Student's ID: ";
        std::cin >> local_id;
        std::cin.ignore();
        if (local_id != -99)
        {
            students[counter].id = local_id;
            students[counter].gpa = 0.0;
            std::cout << "\nEnter the Student's name: ";
            std:getline(std::cin,students[counter].name);
            std::cout << "\nEnter the Student's number of classes: ";
            std::cin >> students[counter].num;
            std::cin.ignore();
            for (int i = 0; i < students[counter].num; i++)
            {
                Class students_classes = students[counter].classes[i];
                std::cout << "Enter the name of class #" << i << ": ";
                std::getline(std::cin, students_classes.name);
                std::cout << "Enter the units of " << students_classes.name << ": ";
                std::cin >> students_classes.units;
                std::cout << "Enter the grade recieved for " << students_classes.name << ": ";
                std::cin >> students_classes.grade;
                std::cout << "************* = " << students_classes.grade;
                std::cin.ignore();
            }
        }
        counter++;
        return counter;
    }
}

double get_gpa(Class local_classes[20],const int classNum)
{
    int counter = 0;
    char grade;
    int intGrade = 0, intGradeTotal = 0, units = 0, unitsTotal = 0, numerator = 0;
    double num = 0.0;
    while (counter < classNum)
    {
        grade = local_classes[counter].grade;
        std::cout << "\nGrade for this class is: " << grade;
        std::cout << "\nGrade for this class is: " <<  local_classes[counter].grade;
        units = local_classes[counter].units;
        std::cout << "\nUnits for this class is: " << units;
        switch (grade)
        {
        case 'A':
            intGrade = 4;
            break;
        case 'B':
            intGrade = 3;
        case 'C':
            intGrade = 2;
            break;
        case 'D':
            intGrade = 1;
            break;
        case 'F':
            intGrade = 0;
            break;
        }
        unitsTotal += units;
        std::cout << "\nAll units = " << unitsTotal;
        num = intGrade * units;
        std::cout << "\nNum = " << num;
        numerator += num;
        counter++;
    }
    std::cout << numerator << "/" << unitsTotal;
    std::cout << "\nAnswer is: " << numerator / unitsTotal;

    return 0.0;
}
```

Hello. I am doing an assignment for class and I'm trying to do some math within the function `get_gpa()` but I'm having trouble because for a reason I can't figure out the information within the nested structure within the `Students` structure is not saving after the function `get_info()` is finished. For example towards the end of the `get_info()` function, the grade received is asked, if the user enters 'A' then it is printed out in the check. (Right after), but it is no longer there when checked once the function is finished. This is really confusing me, The biggest problem is that I don't know **exactly** what I've done wrong, otherwise I would be trying to fix it. Because of this error, the math of `get_gpa()` doesn't work, because it is all based on a switch statement which assumes that there is value within `local_classes[counter].grade`. If you run my code I have added debug statements to help show where the whole thing went down the drain.

Comment: Your title says "passing a structure as a reference" but you aren't using any references.  This suggests that you are used to Java or C#, where the `class` keyword implies a reference.  In C++ it does not, you have full control over making a reference or a copy.

Comment: Sorry, the way my teacher explained it made me think that simply passing an structure the way I did was the same as passing it as a reference.

Comment: Well, it is true that in `double get_gpa(Class local_classes[20],const int);`, the parameter `local_classes` is a **pointer**.  And C programmers often say "pass by reference" when they use pointers.  But C++ has references as a distinct language feature, although they tend to become pointers as a compilation detail, the syntax is different.  Note that you could have used a pointer instead of a reference to solve your problem... anything that indirectly accesses the array inside of the other object, instead of making copies, would work.

Comment: Thank you for that detail, I'm unsure whether my professor is a native C programmer but it would make sense.I couldn't use pointers because the assignment did not permit it.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing the use of `cin >>` and `getline`. This leads to confusing behaviour because `cin >>` does not consume the trailing newline from the input buffer, while `getline` does not expect to see the trailing newline remaining in the buffer.

Use `getline` for all user input and this problem will likely go away. If you need to read a number, use `getline` along with `stoi` or other numeric conversion function.

Comment: Thank you for that advice, I changed the line `std::cin >> students_classes.grade;` to `std::getline(std::cin, students_classes.grade);` and I'm getting an error that says: error no instance of overloaded function std::getline matches the argument list. Weird cause `std::getline` had worked just fine a few lines up.

Comment: @Bryan: `grade` is a `char`. The `getline` function reads into `std::string` values.

Comment: Okay, so how then could I use `std::getline` for all user input as you suggested? How do I use getline in a way that I can also read `char` and `int`?

Comment: @Bryan: Read into a temporary `std::string` value, and then either get the first character from that string (`.at(0)`) or call something like `stoi` to convert the input string to an integer.

Comment: It sounds overly complicated when I could just ensure myself of using `std::cin.ignore()` doesn't it?

Comment: @Bryan: You can do that if you like. But one day, you'll forget to call `ignore()` and your program will suddenly fail in mysterious ways at a location far from the source of the problem.

Comment: @Bryan: No worries. With more programming experience, you'll learn that the human mind is terribly fallible and anything you can do to avoid having to rely on your memory is a good idea. :)

Answer (score 2):

When you do this:

```
Class students_classes = students[counter].classes[i];
```

You are making a *copy* of that object... and then populating the information in the copy. This in no way affects the original `students[counter].classes[i]` object which you wanted to populate.

You need to instead take a *reference*:

```
Class& students_classes = students[counter].classes[i];
     ^
```

Comment: So in effect, what I did was `int a = b;` changed a bunch of stuff to `a` and then returned `b` and wondered why those changes did not apply. Thank you so much.